# Error in loading the data in mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, jupyter-notebook, mysql-connector-python

I was trying to load the data in mysql but then this error is coming can anyone help ?

The table that I created is:

```
mydb=connection.connect(user='root',host='localhost',passwd='',database='Jobs')

cursor=mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE salary1 (Id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,Years_of_Experience FLOAT(4,3),Salary FLOAT(15,3))')
```

The code for inserting data is:

```
with open(salary.csv','r') as data:
next(data)
data_csv=csv.reader(data,delimiter=',')
for j in enumerate(data_csv):
    print(j[1])
    for data_list in j[1]:
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Jobs.salary1 values ({data})'.format(data=(data_list)))
print("All the data inserted ")
mydb.commit()
```

The error is :
[image]

The excel file is :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a placeholder - `"%s"` - in the `VALUES` clause for each column that you are inserting.

```py
# Define an SQL statement that will insert two column
sql = 'INSERT INTO Jobs.salary1 (Years_of_Experience, Salary) values (%s, %s)'

for j in enumerate(data_csv):
    print(j[1])
    _, years, salary = j[1]
        
    # Now execute the sql statement with data_list as parameter
    cursor.execute(sql, (float(years), float(salary)))
```

We pass the data as a parameter to `cursor.execute` rather than formatting it into the SQL statement ourselves to ensure that different data types are quoted correctly, and to guard against SQL injection attacks.

Note that rather than inserting each row individually, it may be more efficient to use `cursor.executemany`

```py
# Define an SQL statement that will insert two column
sql = 'INSERT INTO Jobs.salary1 (Years_of_Experience, Salary) values (%s, %s)'

rows = list(data_csv)
# Make a list with only years of experience and salary values
data = [(float(years), float(salary)) for _, years, salary in rows]

cursor.executemany(sql, data)
```

Comment: Ok, the problem was because the value of the `id` column is autogenerated, we must explicitly declare which columns we are inserting into.  It should work now.

Comment: Please be more specific - do you get the same error?  A different error?  "still not working"  doesn't provide any useful information.

Comment: can I text you somewhere more convenient ? Where I can share you the error

Comment: Can you join [this chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234225/room-for-snakecharmerb-and-annie-dhawan)?